# Can't acces to run settings in project :Simple Javafx maven archetype(gluon) in netbeans 13

Tags: maven, javafx, netbeans, gluon, netbeans-13

I'm trying to change vm options in netbeans 13 and I can't change anything at Run setup.
At the bottom of the run settings throws a warning :  **One of Run/Debug/Profile Project actions has been modified and the Run panel cannot be safely edited**.
Almost everything else works fine : javafx apps can be compiled and run . autocompletion in java works fine in javafx libraries .

openjfx version 17.0.2

javafx maven plugin version 0.0.8

jdk coretto 17 in ubuntu 20.4 64

gluon plugin 2.8.4  on netbeans 13

[image: run settings]

**pom file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.mavenproject7.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: [1] I tried unsuccessfully to reproduce this with your **pom.xml**. [2] Any more details on _"css autcompletion javafx css attributes does not work"_? Is it relevant? [3] The [old NetBeans bug Bug 248079 - Maven JavaFX: Corrupt <default config> cannot be edited/deleted](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=248079) refers to your error msg. The final comment details a possible solution: **{project properties} > Actions > {select Action} >** click the **Remove/Reset** button. Can you try that? If it works please post an accepted answer. Otherwise update your question accordingly.

Comment: Cool. Any idea what you may have done to initially provoke the problem? Can you reproduce it?

Comment: it is default project at  netbeans>>maven>>Simple Javafx maven archetype(gluon)  ( gluon plugin is needed )i've just change javafx from 13 to 17.0.2   and maven plugin from 0.0.4 to 0.0.8  . once is initilized  open project properties>>run  . i have that issue with default values as well : javafx 13 and maven 0.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reset actions run , debug , profile**

In project Properties >> actions  select **Run Project** ,**Debug Project** and **Profile Project** and click **Remove/Reset** button . That will allow to change options in run category . add javafx modules and their paths to vm is needed in order to run and compile javafx projects `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.base,javafx.graphics`   and `--module-path /...path-to-modules`.Follow the thread and you'll find how to solve it at [netbeans Bug 248079](https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=248079)

[image: netbeans properties panel]